# Getting Count of Time Intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Call_Data and the data looks like:

```
Arr_Date      Interval    AN_Time    AB_Time
08/08/2011    1600        113        NULL
08/08/2011    1400        317        NULL
08/09/2011    1200        298        NULL
08/09/2011    1000        NULL       194
08/10/2011    1200        256        NULL
08/10/2011    1400        NULL       132
```

I am looking to get output like:

```
Arr_Date    Total_calls  AN_10_min   AN_5_min   AB_10_Min     AB_5_min
08/08/2011   2             2            1             0           0
08/09/2011   2             1            1             1           1
08/10/2011   2             1            1             1           1
```

The logic is the column AN_Time,AB_Time is in seconds. I want to count the number of calls per day that are within 10min and 5 min range for each column.

I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT  ARR_date,
CASE WHEN AN_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AN_5_min ,
case WHEN AN_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AN_10_min,
CASE WHEN AB_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AB_5_min ,
case WHEN AB_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AB_10_min
FROM Call_Data
GROUP BY AR_Date,AN_TIME,AB_TIME
```

But this doesn't gice me the total numbe of calls. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
SELECT  
  ARR_date,
  COUNT(*)  AS Total_calls,
  SUM( CASE WHEN AN_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  AS AN_5_min ,
  SUM( CASE WHEN AN_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  AS AN_10_min,
  SUM( CASE WHEN AB_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  AS AB_5_min ,
  SUM( CASE WHEN AB_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  AS AB_10_min
FROM Call_Data
GROUP BY AR_Date
```

You can also use `NULL` and `COUNT` to show (to any future coder) that you are actually counting calls and not summing up:

```
SELECT  
  ARR_date,
  COUNT(*)  AS Total_calls,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN AN_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )  AS AN_5_min ,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN AN_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )  AS AN_10_min,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN AB_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )  AS AB_5_min ,
  COUNT( CASE WHEN AB_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )  AS AB_10_min
FROM Call_Data
GROUP BY AR_Date
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just sum the columns up

```
SELECT
    ARR_date,
    SUM(AN_5_min) AN_5_min,
    SUM(AN_10_min) AN_10_min,
    SUM(AB_5_min) AB_5_min,
    SUM(AB_10_min) AB_10_min
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ARR_date,
        CASE WHEN AN_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AN_5_min,
        case WHEN AN_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AN_10_min,
        CASE WHEN AB_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AB_5_min,
        case WHEN AB_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AB_10_min
    FROM
        Call_Data) TBL
GROUP BY
    ARR_date
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) why the subquery? (2) where is the Total_Calls column?

Comment: (1) Sometimes it's easier to see things expanded (2) Add “Count(*) OVER (PARTITION by ARR_Date) as Total_Calls,” should get the Totals

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Arr_Date, COUNT(*) AS Total_Calls,
  SUM(CASE WHEN AN_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AN_5_min ,
  SUM(case WHEN AN_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AN_10_min,
  SUM(CASE WHEN AB_TIME <300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AB_5_min ,
  SUM(case WHEN AB_TIME <600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AB_10_min
FROM dbo.Call_Data
GROUP BY Arr_Date
ORDER BY Arr_Date;
```